# glow around composited framebuffers

Tags: opengl, graphics, webgl

I am trying to draw brush strokes made of quads with a rough texture into framebuffers that are then composited together. The problem is that the framebuffer texture initial color is 0,0,0,0 and it blends in creating a dark glow around the edges. [here is an example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl3XK.jpg)

im using

```
gl.blendEquationSeparate( gl.FUNC_ADD, gl.FUNC_ADD );
gl.blendFuncSeparate( gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE );
```

I think Iv tried every possible combination of blending settings and none work the way I want.

here is a [demo of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/7J4ML/1/)

Comment: How would you want the blended output to be ? Is it possible to add an image showing this ?

Comment: i would like the blended outputs color to not be affected by pixels with 0 alpha. currently transparent pixels blend into the color creating a dark glow on the edges like in the example image.

Comment: here is a comparison of what i want and what im getting [link](http://i.imgur.com/TLmLIVi.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For compositing you most likely want to use pre-multiplied alpha to get the effect you want. Either pre-multiply the texture when you upload the data

```
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true);
```

or pre-multiply in the shader

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb * color.a, color.a);
```

And blend with

```
 gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

[A quick google of "pre-multiplied alpha blending"](https://www.google.com/search?q=premultiplied%20alpha%20blending) brought up [this great explanation](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/alpha-blending-pre-or-not-pre) of the issue

Comment: i tried multiplying in the fragment shader and set 'gl.enable( gl.BLEND );
gl.blendEquationSeparate( gl.FUNC_ADD, gl.FUNC_ADD );
gl.blendFuncSeparate( gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE );' but it still has a faint glow [example](http://i.imgur.com/HdS9Pt9.jpg)

Comment: I did find that setting the clear color to the same as the texture but transparent eg gl.clearColor(BrushRed , BrushGreen, BrushBlue , 0.0 ) and then clearing the bound framebuffer before drawing fixed the glow. This would not work for multicolored textures though.

Comment: Did you set the color of the page or the canvas itself in CSS or is it the default? By default the canvas is composited with the page using `gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`. If you see a CSS color for the canvas it will be composited with that color.

otherwise here's a jsfiddle using un-premultiplied red and premultiplying in the shader.

http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/SY5Xr/

Comment: I setup a demo of my code with the bad rendering could you take a look and spot where i goofed? [http://jsfiddle.net/7J4ML/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/7J4ML/1/)

Comment: never mind i think i got it to composite correctly [http://jsfiddle.net/7J4ML/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/7J4ML/7/)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a pre-multiplication issue to me. Either your brush stroke textures aren't pre-multiplied and they should be, or they are pre-multiplied and they shouldn't be - I forget which.